# The origin of a certain coin weighing problem using spring scale

Tags: reference-request, puzzle

Youtube channel Vsause2 recently posted a [video on coin weighing problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNgshmsXpCc).
While the video is more or less an advertisement of their merchandise,
the origin of the problem remains mysterious and catches my interest.

The problem reads:
There are 50 rolls of pennies, each consisting of 50 pennies.
Among them, 49 rolls are true pennies; each true penny weighs 2.5g.
But one roll consists of 50 fake pennies, each fake penny weighs 2.4g.
Use the spring scale *once* to figure out which roll is the fake roll.

I would like to know the origin of this problem.

Also consider the following variants:

- (P2) You know that a true penny weighs 2.5g but
  don't know how much a fake penny weights
  (but you do know that fake pennies weigh the same).
  Then you need to use the spring scale *twice*.
- (P3) you don't know how much pennies weigh
  (but true pennies weigh the same, and fake pennies weigh the same)
  Then you need to use the spring scale *three times*.

Essentially these are just linear algebra with integer coefficients ≤ 50.
So I doubt that they had appeared in any *official* source
(Martin Gardner's books, for instance).
But I would like to hear if they had appeared before.

Comment: I saw this as a kid over 50 years ago.  I would be surprised if someone can find the original source and be sure it is the original.  I have been surprised before.

Comment: In that case, let me rephrase my question: I will be satisfied by anything *citable*, without worrying about promoting someone else's merchandise.

Comment: I'd have a look at some of the old puzzle books, like Dudeney, Kraitchik, Ball, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this was the original source, but it did turn up in Martin Gardner, Hexaflexagons and Other Mathematical Diversions, Chapter Three, Nine Problems, Problem 9, pp. 26-27, solutions pp. 35-36. This is the first of the variations you mention.

Comment: Thank you so much. It must be difficult to find a specific puzzle in books without being distracted by so many interesting problems.